# How to map an object of arrays with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to map an object of arrays. Once mapped I want to display the first row of content in a div. I have an object of arrays coming from the db and I'm only mapping 2 of the 4 arrays within the object.

What I want to be able to do is use the mapped arrays and then get all the data that corresponds with that mapped array and display it all in a div. The user can click an up or down arrow and then change what is displayed, but I'm having trouble getting it to show the next or prev data in the object. I have the clicking function properly set up (worked with test data) just think it's not working because I'm not mapping it correctly.

Original object coming from db:

```
object: {
    PageNum: [array of items],
    RowNum: [array of items],
    CustomerName: [array of items],
    FacilityName: [array of items]
}
```

mapping the arrays:

```
var delDS = [{
    pageNum : delPageData["PageNum"],
    rowNum : delPageData["RowNum"]
}];

var delMappedArray = delDS.map(function(obj) {
    var rObj = {};
    rObj[obj.pageNum] = obj.rowNum;
    return rObj;
});
```

which returns something like this:

```
[object]
   0: Object
     2,2,4,4,6: Array(5)
      0: "24"
      1: "26"
      2: "2"
      3: "4"
      4: "10"
     length: 5
```

Comment: _which returns something like this_, so is that what you wanted? Or not? What did you want? What is actually the problem you are having?

Comment: This isn't so clear. What kind of *items* you have in those properties `[array of items]` ?

Comment: I want to be able to use the mapped data and get the correct customer name and facility name that belongs to the correct mapped data item. So that way I can display the correct rowNum, pageNum, customerName, and facilityName. For example right now it may have rowNum 3 but the customerName for rowNum 8.

Comment: They're numbers or names in the array of items

Comment: or is there a way that I can nicely sort the whole object so that each array of items matches the correct items?

Comment: @JBaldwin: _For example right now it may have rowNum 3 but the customerName for rowNum 8_ It's still not really clear what you are asking. Is it the case that `PageNum[n]` corresponds to `RowNum[n]`, `CustomerName[n]` and `FacilityName[n]`? Are you trying to transform them into a single array of objects?

Comment: Yes they all correspond together, just they aren't all sorted correctly when coming from the db. So I want to be able to correctly sort them or map them so I can get the correct data and display it in a div. I'm really not sure about the single array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    //map the data
    delPD = delPageData.PageNum.map((x,i) => ({
            pageNum: x,
            rowNum: delPageData["RowNum"][i],
            cName: delPageData["CustomerName"][i],
            fName: delPageData["FacilityName"][i],
    }));
    //sort the data
    delPD.sort(function(a,b) {
        if(a.pageNum == b.pageNum) {
            return (a.rowNum - b.rowNum);
        } else {
            return (a.pageNum - b.pageNum);
        }
    });
    //give the data an index number for ordering purposes later
    for(var i=0; i<delPD.length; i++) {
        delPD[i].index = i;
    }
```

This is first mapping the array of objects and creating a new array. Then you are sorting the new array by page numbers and putting them in order. Then you're adding an index number to each object. This way you can use it later in your code if need be.

Hope this helps!